# Singleton Connection changes config. Best way to do

Tags: java, http, singleton

I have a Singleton Class to connect to http server. But the user can change the connection Host and Port. What is the best (most correct) way to update my singleton class?

My code:

```
public class ServletConnectionManager{

    private static ServletConnectionManager INSTANCE = new ServletConnectionManager(Cloud.getServlet_Port(), Cloud.getServlet_Host());

    public ServletConnectionManager(String hostPort, String hostName) {

        super();

        this.setHostName(hostName);

        this.setHostPort(hostPort);

        this.setServerURL("http://" + hostName + ":" + hostPort);

    }   
}
```

Thank you very much. 
Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Not a singleton since your constructor is public.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good idea. Why do you want a globally mutable singleton? Maybe use a pool of connections, instead?

Comment: I Know, I make public recently to do some tests. Originally was private

Comment: Do you really need to make this a singleton? Have you considered designing a proper object instead? One that you can construct as you need? You should realize that you are inflicting this issue upon yourself simply because you decided to make this a *singleton* "manager" class. If you drop the singleton requirements, it will be easy.

Comment: I created a Singleton becouse on past, was allways the same Host and Port, so singleton was ok. Now, I need to make possible to change Host and Port, so, maybe the best idea is change it to a regular class, dont you think?

Comment: If your test class is in the same package as the class under test, you can make the constructor `protected`, and the test class will still be able to see it. In Java, `protected` means "accessible to heirs as well as classes inside the same package".

Comment: @Mark: exactly. Think about what you gained by making it a singleton back then. That's what you will be "losing" by changing it to a sane class. (Nothing?) Let this be a lesson you will remember next time you consider a singleton. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add yet another synchronized method to reset the connection based on new server location/user credentials changes. Even if doned transparently, you would have to make something similar when trying to reconnect after losing connection temporarily.